# Angular.js - How to pass data from controller to view

Tags: angularjs

This is the first time i am using Angular.js. So my workflow could be wrong.

How do i pass data from controller to the view

1. ng-view -> Displays html page using jade
2. When user clicks on submit button, i use $http on the controller and submit the request to the server.
3. The server returns me the necessary data back which i need to pass to another view.

My code snippet

```
function TrackController($scope,$http,$location,MessageFactory){
  $scope.message = MessageFactory.contactMessage();

  $scope.submit = function () {
    var FormData = {
        'track_applicationid': $scope.track_applicationid,
        'track_email': $scope.track_email
    }
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/track', data: FormData}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.registeredDate = 'data.REGISTERED_DATE';
        $scope.filedDate = data.FILED_DATE;
        $location.path('trackMessage');
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
      });   
}
}
```

In the above code, i want to pass registeredDate and filedDate to trackMessage view.

Comment: in the view if your interpolate {{registeredDate}} it will automatically update view  .I will recommend you studying databinding in angularjs.

Comment: I tried before posting. It didn't work. If you see the code above, i interpolate {{message}} which works fine. If i interpolate {{registeredDate}} which is inside $http.success function it doesn't work.

Comment: why u are adding location.path in success method ?

Comment: I want to re-direct to a different page when i get the result back from the server. The new page (trackMessage) also uses the same controller.

Comment: when you redirect to new location a new instance of controller will be created which will wipe old values they are not preserved so pls think about other approach

Answer (score 0):

After going through the comments, i understood you are using one controller for two views. 
If you want to set values to `$scope.registeredDate` and `$scope.filedDate`, You have to declare those objects globally using root-scope(Not recommended) or
use Angular values.

I recommended to use two different controllers.